# How to perform if statement for a certain timeperiod

Tags: php, datetime, if-statement

I want to perform certain tasks in PHP between Monday 10:00am till Saturday 10:00am and I want to perform other tasks between Saturday 10:30am till Monday 10am. **Every week.**

I am sorry if that's a silly question. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: answer will depend on that theses tasks are

Comment: run a cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running a time triggered task run a cron job or if it is a user triggered like website and you want to change page according to day then use if else statement to select task.

you can get the time in weekday and hour:minute::second  for if else selection using this

```
$d = new DateTime('Sunday,23:23:48 ');  //set time  day time format
echo $d->format('l , H:i:s ');

$date = new DateTime();   // get current datetime

echo $date->format('l , H:i:s ');   //php get time in day time format

//output example  Sunday , 23:23:48 Sunday , 23:34:47
```

Comment: I want to truncate a table from db during (Mon 10am till Sat 9am) I am running the php using BAT every hour.
But I don't want to truncate the table AFTER 10am Sat till am Monday.

Comment: then use if else statement in  your php script to select action

Comment: sample code  [sample code ](https://expirebox.com/download/112a77572eedd511aa07a51e1c571633.html)  file will be deleted after 48h automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
$currentTime = time();
$time = date('H:i',$currentTime);  
$date = date('h:i:s a', time());
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$day = date('D', $timestamp);


if ( ( ($day == "Sat") && ($time < 11) ) || ($day == "Mon" && $time > 9) )

{
     # weekday then truncate table
}
```